# Get list of folders that are after certain number

Tags: bash, awk, filenames, date

I have a folder which subfolder naming convention is like `yyyymm` for e.g. 200801, 200803 etc. I want to list down folder after 201412 via command line means to upload to S3. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: don't we fave files in the same location and don't we have any folderName with string in the same location?

Comment: given the bash tag, I won't answer with this, but consider zsh. If you can safely assume the date/directory name format (e.g. no 201413 directory), then `zsh -c 'print -l <201413->(/)'` would get them.

Comment: Welcome to U/L! 6 answers and no upvotes to the question… have a +1!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

list directory content, pipe output to awk, print only those which values are greater or equal than the date you want, pipe to xargs s3.

`ls | awk '$1 >= 201412 {print $1}' | xargs -n1 YOUR_S3_COPY_COMMAND -options`

If it is a lot of of directories and files, you can parallelize xargs with -P number of concurrent processes.

`ls | awk '$1 >= 201412 {print $1}' | xargs -n1 -P20 YOUR_S3_COPY_COMMAND -options`

Comment: it says Unknown options: 201501,201502,201503,201504,201505,201506,201507,201508,201509,201510,201511,201512,201601,201602,201603,201604,201605,201606,201607,201608,201609,201610,201611,201612,201701,201702,201703,201704,201705,201706,201707,201708,201709,201710,201711,201712,201801,201802,201803,201804,201805,201806,201807,201808,201809,201810,201811,201812,201901,201902,201903

Comment: show me the command you're running.

Comment: ok i got it. it needs the -n1 in the xargs command

I was running `ls | awk -v snumber=201412 '$1>snumber {print $1}' | xargs aws s3 sync {$1} s3://s3-static-zaobao/s3fs-public/images/ --acl public-read --dryrun`

Comment: You're right. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your current requirement is to list subdirectory names that are *after* `201412`, i.e. `201501` or later.

These directories would match the pattern `201[5-9]*`.
To also handle names after 2019 (until 2099), use `201[5-9]* 20[2-9]*`.

To list them:

```
shopt -s nullglob # to allow non-matching globs to expand to nothing
printf '%s\n' somedir/201[5-9]*/ somedir/20[2-9]*/
```

where `somedir` is the directory where your subdirectories are kept.

To do something with each of these:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for dir in somedir/201[5-9]*/ somedir/20[2-9]*/; do
   aws s3 cp "$dir" ...
done
```

Note: I've never used S3, so I would not know the correct command to use for uploading a directory of files.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can do it directly so you need to get the list of directories and then filter the output. Command like this can help:

```
ls|awk -v snumber=201412 '$1>snumber {print}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 find . -type d  -regex '^./[0-9]+' -exec sh -c 'test "{}" ">" "./201412"' \; -print
```

As I have queried in comments. The current directory may have files in and non-numeric directory names

- `type -d` will list only the directories
- `-regex '^./[0-9]+'` will list only the names with numeric
- `test` is used to compare the result

Here you can add `maxdepth` to restrict the search to current directory, but our `regex` itself will do the same.

Comment: There's no real reason to use `sh -c` with `-exec` here, is there?

Answer (score 0):

i have just listing you replace ls command with as per your requirement

```
ls -ltr | awk '$1 ~ /^d/{print $0}'|sed -n '/[0-9]\{6\}/p'| awk '$NF >= "201412" {print "ls -ltr "$NF}'| sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a variation of a now-deleted answer to build up an array of desired files in bash:

```
$ mkdir 201412 201501 201705 202003

$ files=()
$ for d in */
do
  (( d > 201412)) && files+=("$d")
done
$ declare -p files
declare -a files='([0]="201501" [1]="201705" [2]="202003")'
```

You could then safely loop over that array (or expand it all out) to upload it, such as:

```
$ aws upload command "${files[@]}"
```